# Animating Trisurf Plots in Plotly

Tags: python, animation, plotly-python

I have some data points stored in the variable `z`. Given the coordinates (`xy[:,0] and xy[:,1]`  read from a file and the triangulations (Also read from a file), I plotted the trisurf with plotly as :

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np

#xy is read from a file 
#triangulations is also read from a file
#z is also read from a file


fig1 = ff.create_trisurf(x=xy[:,0], y=xy[:,1], z=z,
                         simplices=triangle,
                         title=" ",show_colorbar=True)


fig1.show()
```

The code above gives the trisurf plot for the given z. Now, I have many files containing different z values and I want to create the trisurf plot for all those values and animate them. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74526203/how-to-create-a-plotly-animation-from-a-list-of-figure-objects) and [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/animating-traces-on-trisurf/4437) link, I came up with a way to animate the plotly trisurf.

I did the following modifications:

```
#z= Read from a file
frames=[]
for i in range(2,8):
    fig=ff.create_trisurf(x=xy[:,0], y=xy[:,1], z=z,
                         simplices=triangle,
                         title=" ",show_colorbar=True)
    #z= Now read another file

    # fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":50,"l":0,"b":0})
    frames += [go.Frame(data=(fig.data[0],fig.data[1]), layout=fig.layout, name=i)]

    if i == 2:
        first_fig = fig

fig = go.Figure(frames=frames)

## add the first frame to the figure so it shows up initially
fig.add_trace(first_fig.data[0],)
fig.layout = first_fig.layout


## the rest is coped from the plotly documentation example on mri volume slices
def frame_args(duration):
    return {
            "frame": {"duration": duration},
            "mode": "immediate",
            "fromcurrent": True,
            "transition": {"duration": duration, "easing": "linear"},
        }

sliders = [
            {
                "pad": {"b": 10, "t": 60},
                "len": 0.9,
                "x": 0.1,
                "y": 0,
                "steps": [
                    {
                        "args": [[f.name], frame_args(0)],
                        "label": str(k),
                        "method": "animate",
                    }
                    for k, f in enumerate(fig.frames)
                ],
            }
        ]

fig.update_layout(
         title='Slices in volumetric data',
         width=1200,
         height=600,
         scene=dict(
                    zaxis=dict(range=[-0.1, 6.8], autorange=False),
                    aspectratio=dict(x=1, y=1, z=1),
                    ),
         updatemenus = [
            {
                "buttons": [
                    {
                        "args": [None, frame_args(50)],
                        "label": "&#9654;", # play symbol
                        "method": "animate",
                    },
                    {
                        "args": [[None], frame_args(0)],
                        "label": "&#9724;", # pause symbol
                        "method": "animate",
                    },
                ],
                "direction": "left",
                "pad": {"r": 10, "t": 70},
                "type": "buttons",
                "x": 0.1,
                "y": 0,
            }
         ],
         sliders=sliders
)

fig.show()
```

This works and it does animates. However, the problem is that the z data is "suppressed". What I mean is that prior to the modifications, the plot looked like this:
[image]

However, after modifying for the animation, the plot now looks like this:
[image]
[image]

As can be seen, the z data is suppresed(Though the color bar gives the information about the z values, I want to have plots like the image above prior to the modification. They give better visualization.

Any way to solve the above problem?

Thank You in advance.